# How do I unit test random shuffle operations in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have written code to create a Secret Santa list from a .csv file with groups of names and corresponding emails.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

def compare(list_of_names, list_of_emails):
    zipped_lists = list(zip(list_of_emails, list_of_names))
    random.shuffle(zipped_lists)  # shuffle list of emails and names
    result = []
    shuffled_emails = [i[0] for i in zipped_lists]
    for i, _ in enumerate(shuffled_emails):
        result.append(zipped_lists[i-1][1])  # shift email relatively one position to the right
    return list(zip(result, shuffled_emails))

def main():
    names  = ["John", "Bob", "Alice"]
    emails = ["John@gmail.com", "Bob@gmail.com", "Alice@outlook.com"]

    print(compare(names,emails))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I unit test this code, since I am using random shuffle operations? I am not sure how I could write a test case for the same.

Comment: I'm not sure how all the comments just got deleted. I have a question regarding the solution. How did you come with the specific seed '0xBEEF'? What is its significance? Can it be a different seed? @MadPhysicist

Comment: There is no significance to that seed beyond the fact that I think it looks cool. *Any* seed should produce a deterministic stream of numbers. The shuffle order will not change between runs if you don't change the seed, but it doesn't matter what the seed is as long as it stays the same. If you use a different seed, you will likely have to change the order of `expected`, but nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common approach would be to seed the random number generator in the test, generate a dataset and verify it by hand. The test will then serve as a regression test to ensure that the implementation did not change. If the implementation does change, you will be forced to regenerate the dataset and manually re-verify.

For example:

```
def test_compare():
    seed = 0xBEEF
    names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Cuthbert', 'Daisy', 'Ethelred']
    emails = [f'{n}@company.com' for n in names]

    expected = [('Alice', 'Cuthbert@company.com'), ('Cuthbert', 'Bob@company.com'), ('Bob', 'Daisy@company.com'), ('Daisy', 'Ethelred@company.com'), ('Ethelred', 'Alice@company.com')]

    random.seed(seed)

    #k = list(zip(emails, names))
    #random.shuffle(k)
    #print(k)

    assert compare(names, emails) == expected

test_compare()
```

The first time I ran the test, I ran the commented out lines instead of the assertion, and manually constructed the list `expected`. After that, the assertion should pass until you change the seed or the implementation of `compare`.

In a broader sense, you are trying to assert something deterministic about the function you are testing. Random seeds exist exactly to make this possible. Since you are not testing the properties of `random.shuffle`, using a bunch of hard-coded quantities is perfectly fine.